# use of nickname and nicename?

Tags: username

nicename is used for author slug in url.
But can anyone tell what is the especial use/application of 'nickname' user meta field in wordpress ? or it is just another extra field to show nickname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nickname` field is one of the options made available for choice in "Display name publicly as" option in user profile.

It has no other use in core code, as far as I know.